# series of $\arctan \frac{2x^2}{n^2}$ .

Tags: summation

Find : $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan \frac{2x^2}{n^2}.$$ Where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Taylor series of $\arctan$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan \frac{t}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m (t/n^2)^{2m+1}}{2m+1} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{2m+1} t^{2m+1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{4m+2}} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m \zeta(4m+2)}{2m+1} t^{2m+1} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{B_{4m+2}(2\pi)^{4m+2}}{(4m+2)(4m+2)!} t^{2m+1}.
$$
(I don't know if that actually leads to Lucian's formula, though...)

Comment: Does not seem to lead anywhere, can you elaborate ?

Comment: The next step would be to relate the final expression to the series $t/(e^t-1)$, though you would have to cancel somehow the terms $B_{4m}$ (which I don't see how), and to take care of the denominator (which is doable). Perhaps you can throw in some effort as well?

Answer (score 4):

$\qquad\quad$ There is indeed a very beautiful closed form expression for this series, in terms of

$$k\pi+\dfrac\pi2-\arctan\bigg(\dfrac{\tan\pi x+\tanh\pi x}{\tan\pi x-\tanh\pi x}\bigg)$$

where *k* is $0$ on the interval $(0,A_0),~1$ on the interval $(A_0,A_1),~2$ on the interval $(A_1,A_2),~$ etc. where $A_k>0$ are the roots of the transcendental equation $\tan\pi x=\tanh\pi x$. The entire graphic is symmetrical with regards to the vertical axis Oy, since the series is even. Also, $A_k\simeq k+\frac54$.

Comment: The case $2x^2=1$ corresponds to [Wilf's constant](https://oeis.org/A091007), mentioned [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html).

Comment: Is it possible to provide/source a proof of that result?

Comment: @Semiclassical: See Achille Hui's comment on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960877) related question.

Comment: That's where I came from, actually. But I still feel like it'd help the answer here to fill that in...

Comment: @Semiclassical: I agree. :-$)$ *Unfortunately*, however, I am not the one to have come up with that particular explanation. *My* approach was based on a combination of high-precision, computer-aided numerical computations, OEIS, ISC, MathWorld articles, and a bit of reverse engineering.