# Random Wolfram|Alpha identity related to $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\tan^{-1}}{\frac{1}{k^2}}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I was watching a Numberphile video (on how $\tan^{-1}{1} + \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2} + \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3} = \frac{\pi}{2}$) and I thought about whether the series
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\tan^{-1}}{\frac{1}{k}}$$

converges.

Turns out, it doesn't. However, it *also* turns out that
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\tan^{-1}}{\frac{1}{k^2}}$$
does converge, to the expression
$$\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{
{1-\cot{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}} \tanh{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}}
}{
{1+\cot{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}} \tanh{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}}
}\right)}$$

Could someone help me understand how this comes about?

Comment: The resulting fraction is intriguingly similar to a summand of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/523610/137524), though that may merely be coincidental.

Comment: $$\tan^{-1}(t) = \frac{1}{2i} \log\left(\frac{1+it}{1-it}\right)
\quad\text{ AND }\quad\frac{\sinh\pi x}{\pi x} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)$$

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956172).

Comment: It turns out a similar question has been asked [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/128357/59379) and has good answers. I wonder whether we should close this as an abstract duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the logarithmic form $\arctan x=\frac1{2i}\ln\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}$ to rewrite the sum as
$$S=\frac1{2i}\ln\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+\frac{i}{k^2}}{1-\frac{i}{k^2}}$$
and combine the result with Euler's infinite product
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{a^2}{k^2}\right)=\frac{\sinh \pi a}{\pi a}.$$
This gives
$$S=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\left(e^{-i\pi/2}\frac{\sinh \pi e^{i\pi/4}}{\sinh \pi e^{-i\pi/4}}\right)=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{\sinh \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}\cos\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2} +i\cosh \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}\cos\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}}{\cosh \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}\sin\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2} +i\sinh \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}\cos\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}}\right),$$
which can be straightforwardly reduced to the quoted result.